# Oracle 11g SQL: Can you use a dblink called up from a dblink

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Say you have a database A which has a stored dblink to database B, and database B has a stored dblink to database C.

Is there a way to run a query from A on data which is on C?

I've tried

```
Select * from ALL_DB_LINKS@B@C
```

Which does not work (for me at least)

Answer (score 1):

In B, you can create a synonym for `object_name@C`.  In A, you can then query `synonym_name@B`.

Obviously, that's not going to be the most efficient approach in the world-- moving data across the network twice, enlisting three databases in a two-phase commit, and ensuring that any predicates (or joins) are applied in the correct database would be a highly non-trivial endeavor.